# Cloudformation: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: Unsupported

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I tried to deploy a new EC2 instance in cloud formation but I am getting the error "Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: Unsupported"

This is my code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: vm stack

Resources:
  VMParameter:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: Testing
      Type: "String"
      Value: !Ref VMerr
      Description: The ID of the created VM


  VMerr:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      InstanceType: 't2.micro'
      ImageId: ami-007a607c4abd192db
      KeyName: pemtest
      EbsOptimized: True
    
    
      SubnetId: subnet-0ec24f346062f4527      
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - sg-092f790dccf3ed4d3
      BlockDeviceMappings: 
        - DeviceName: "/dev/sdm"
          Ebs: 
            VolumeType: "io1"
            Iops: "200"
            DeleteOnTermination: "false"
            VolumeSize: "20"
        - DeviceName: "/dev/sdk"
          NoDevice: {}
```

Comment: running in `us-east-1`, right? and that `ami`, `subnet`, and `securityGroup` are all in `us-east-1` in that account?

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure to pick the right AMI for the selected instance type. The AMI you specified is `arm64` based. Therefore it is not suitable (`unsupported`) to run on an `t2.micro`.

For an automation one can also you the public Systems Manager Parameter Stores:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/